# Edit and delete a UITableView row using UIMenuController

Tags: uitableview, uigesturerecognizer, uimenucontroller, uimenuitem

I have a `UITableView` that displays the data from my `plist`. Is there any way I could edit/delete the `row`'s data using `UIMenuController`?

It would be fine to use the traditional swipe-the-row in order to edit/delete the row, but I am using `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to display my `secondViewController` - this view controller is where I could add a data to my `plist`.

The `UIMenuItem` shows up, but I don't know how to proceed from here.

It would be greatly appreciated if someone could walk me through.

This is my `longPressHandler` which triggers my `UIMenuController`.

```
- (void)longPressHandler:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    if ([sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        [self becomeFirstResponder];

        CGPoint point = [sender locationInView:[self myTableView]];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath =[[self myTableView] indexPathForRowAtPoint:point];

        UIMenuController *menuController = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];

        UIMenuItem *editFruit = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit" action:@selector(editFruit)];
        UIMenuItem *deleteFruit = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Delete" action:@selector(deleteFruit)];

        [menuController setTargetRect:[[self myTableView] rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]
                               inView:[self myTableView]];
        [menuController setMenuItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:editFruit, deleteFruit, nil]];

        [menuController setMenuVisible:YES
                              animated:YES];
    }
}
```

This is where it ends.

```
- (void)deleteFruit
{
    NSLog(@"Delete.");
}

- (void)editFruit
{
    NSLog(@"Edit.");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have all you need there.

So in your deleteFruit method, simply delete the item at that indexPath you've found, and call -deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: on the tableview.